# How to convert arary of byte of defaultdict to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, byte, numpy-ndarray, hdf5

I read from a h5 file with this code:

```
f = h5py.File(fname, "r")
data = f.get('table1')[...]
```

the data is like this:

```
array(b"defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'B': [{'score': 4, 'skin': 3, 'cars': ['bmw'], 'house': 1], 'A': [{'score': 4, 'skin': 3, 'cars': ['bmw'], 'house': 1]}
```

how can I save it to a dictionary?

```
d = {'B': [{'score': 4, 'skin': 3, 'cars': ['bmw'], 'house': 1], 'A': [{'score': 4, 'skin': 3, 'cars': ['bmw'], 'house': 1]}
```

I tried to decode the bytes but it didn't work, I need to read from a h5 file and save it in a dictionary.

Comment: The file contains the text representation of a defaultdict? Why?

Comment: Because it's saved f.create_dataset('table1', data = str(d))

Comment: Don't use `str(d)`. Convert it to a standard format like JSON.

Comment: So, I need to save a dictionary into h5 then read it in another code. I used this code:f.create_dataset('prec_info', data = str(d)) to save it, but I couldn't load it into a dictionary

Comment: Use `data=json.dumps(d)` when writing, and then use `json.loads()` to parse it when you read from the file.

Comment: How can I convert it to a JSON format? I am naive in hdf5.

Comment: I just showed you.

Comment: HDF5 is intended for numeric data like numpy arrays, not text.

Comment: I have a big data, I used pickle but the size got to 25G so to reduce the size and make it efficient I used h5.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using pickle's loads method?

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import pickle
...
d = defaultdict(list, pickle.loads(data))
```